# Set inclusion between space of probabilities

Tags: analysis, lp-spaces

I'm working with sets of probability measures of the form:
$$
\mathscr{P}_p(\Omega) := \left\{\mu \in \mathscr P: \int_\Omega |x|^p d\mu < + \infty\right\}
$$
and I'm trying to show that if $p<q$, then $\mathscr P_p(\Omega)\subset \mathscr P_q(\Omega)$

My immediate thought was to try something like Holder's inequality starting with
$$
\int|x|^qd\mu = \| |x|^q\cdot 1\|_{L^1(\Omega, \mu)}
$$
and trying to find $\|x\|_p$ in some form as an upper bound, but the conjugate exponents don't seem to work out since $p<q$.

My other idea was to consider the largest natural number $m\ge2$ such that $q-mp\ge 0$, and split the integral
$$
\int|x|^qd\mu = \int |x|^{mp}|x|^{q-mp}d\mu
$$
and try to use a generlized Holder inequality and the fact that $q-mp < p$ since $m$ is maximal. The issue I seemed to run into again was that the conjugate exponent would bring me back to the $q$-norm, which certainly isn't what I want.

I considered Jensen's inequality (which I don't know very well), but I don't think it works out since $t\mapsto t^{p/q}$ isn't convex.

I'd like to still solve this somewhat on my own, so if you can just nudge me in the right direction or critique my ideas, I'd greatly appreciate that. Thank you!

Comment: $q/p$ and $q/(q-p)$ are conjugate exponents. Apply Hölder's inequality.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I believe I tried this but the issue is that I'm trying to go to from the q-norm to the p-norm, so using these conjugate exponents I end up with something like
$$
\int\left(|x|^q\right)^{q/p}
$$

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, if you are using $q/p$ and $q/(q-p)$ as your conjugate exponents, then the most you can do is say that
$$
\int |x|^qd\mu = \|x^q\|_1 \le \|x^q\|_{q/p} \cdot \|1\|_{q/(q-p)} = \left(\int\left(|x|^q\right)^{q/p}\right)^{p/q}
$$
i.e. you don't reciprocate $q/p$ for the integrand.

Comment: You are facing trouble because  $\mathscr P_p(\Omega)\subset \mathscr P_q(\Omega)$ is false. What is true is $\mathscr P_q(\Omega)\subset \mathscr P_p(\Omega)$

Comment: Ah. This is probably a typo in my textbook then. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counter-example: On $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure let $x(t)=\frac 1 {\sqrt t}$. Take $p=1, q=2$.

What is true is $\mathscr P_q(\Omega)\subset \mathscr P_p(\Omega)$ and this follows by Hölder's inequality with exponents $\frac q p$ and $\frac q {q-p}$